# SugarCRM API Query - getting Access Denied?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am running SugarCRM 6.5.x and using the SOAP API. What I am trying to achieve is lookup an Account by checking the value of a custom field with the company registration number like this:

```
get_entry_list(...

accounts.id in (select id_c from accounts_cstm join accounts on accounts_cstm.id_c = accounts.id where accounts_cstm.company_number__c = '12345678')

... )
```

I keep getting access denied errors and I don't understand why? If I run the query in phpmyadmin it works fine? How can I make this work for SugarCRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for subqueries like that in our Web Services API is removed as of Sugar 6.4, with certain exceptions; see this post for more details...

http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2012/03/19/howto-avoiding-subqueries-with-our-web-services/

For this one, you shouldn't need to do the subquery as the cstm is joined in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you opened a session and send the right parameters?

```
get_entry_list($session, $module_name, $query, $order_by,$offset, $select_fields, $link_name_to_fields_array, $max_results, $deleted )
```

Take a look at the [API Description](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.4/Developer_Guides/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.4.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_640.html#9000493) and search for "Call: get_entry_list()". 
It's for 6.4 but shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes I am sure - I have another query that's searching the email addresses table and that works fine

Comment: I would use the debugger. What IDE do you use? I use Netbeans and there together with xdebug it's easy to set a breakpoint in service/core/SugarWebServiceImpl.php get_entry_list to see whats going on

Comment: If you don't want to set up the debugger, then you could also change some of the $GLOBALS['log']->info to $GLOBALS['log']->fatal( this makes it easier to read the sugarcrm.log and you see where your problem starts.

Comment: I am interfacing with an existing SugarCRM through the API - let's assume I don't have access to the machine that's running it.

Comment: set up a local installation and try it there first. always a good way to work first locally and after figuring all out you publish.